# CommandParameter Binding (From Nested Child Control to Parent Control)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm refactoring some legacy WPF code that has the following structure -

ChildControl -> ParentControl -> ParentView

ChildControl has a DependencyProperty of type ICommand.  ParentControl has a DependencyProperty of type ICommand.  ParentView binds to a ViewModel, let's call it ParentViewModel, and exposes a public property of type ICommand.

ChildControl has a ContextMenu, where one of the menu items needs to have the Command property bind to the ICommand property in ParentViewModel.  So, the DataContext of the ContextMenu is bound to the PlacementTarget of itself, and the Command property on the MenuItem is bound to the DependencyProperty of type ICommand in ChildControl.

ParentControl, which exposes ChildControl, binds the ICommand DependencyProperty in the ChildControl to the ICommand DependencyProperty in ParentControl.

ParentView, which exposes ParentControl, binds the ICommand DependencyProperty in ParentControl to the ICommand Property in ParentViewModel.

This works, however, what I need is for the CommandParameter on the MenuItem in ChildControl to be bound to the underlying ViewModel (let's call it ChildViewModel).  I get the fact that the above approach is poor.  This is code I inherited and unfortunately I can't change the current structure (i.e. having a ParentView that exposes a ParentControl that exposes a ChildControl), so, I'm looking for ideas on how to do this in a way such that the Command and CommandParameter properties on MenuItem in ChildControl can bind to the Command property in ParentViewModel, so that the instance of ChildControl's DataContext is passed as the Command's parameter.

Example of the approach I'm trying to take below:

```
    <UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem 
            Header="Add" 
            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code that you are working with?

Comment: Just edited my question to include a code example.

Comment: @Chris When text is large, try to describe your problem with a well annotated image.

Comment: In the last para, you are saying : "what I need is for the CommandParameter on the MenuItem in ChildControl to be bound to the underlying ViewModel (let's call it ChildViewModel)",        and in the end u are saying : "I'm looking for ideas on how to do this in a way such that the Command and CommandParameter properties on MenuItem in ChildControl can bind to the Command property in ParentViewModel". So, u are not sure what you are binding and to whome ? ChildControl<>ChildViewModel, or ChildControl<>ParentViewModel. So, list your requirements point-wise in the end carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Now you didn't mention MVVM,  but I am assuming that's what you want.

Each view should have a ViewModel.
And viewModel of each view should be assigned as views datacontext.
That way you can bind your commands or any other data to the viewModel of the view.

From your viewModel you can handle what should happen.

Let's say you have ParentView.DoSomeCrazyStuff() and you want to trigger that from your ChildView.TriggerSomeCrazyStuffCommand, the you should bind your command to a button on your childView and from childViewModel trigger it.

And you can from your ParentViewModel assign ChildViewModel to ChildView.DataContext, and sent ParentViewModel as parameter.